# fread() на си - инверсия байтов

Tags: c

Добрый день. Имеется бинарный файл, информация в котором представлена в виде шестнадцатеричных октетов. Пусть содержание файла такое: "01 31 A4 F5". Требуется считать первые два байта, и далее перевести в десятичное число. Делаю это так:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {

FILE *ptrFile = fopen("/path/file.bin", "rb")
int *num = (int *) malloc(2); //выделил в памяти 2 байта, привел указатель к типу int
fread(num, 1, 2, ptrFile); //считываю из файла 2 элемента размером 1 байт каждый в блок памяти num
printf("hex num is %X\n", *num); //вывод считанной инфы в hex виде
printf("dec num is %d\n", *num); //вывод считанной инфы в dec виде

return 0;
}
```

В результате вместо того чтобы получить

```
hex num is 131
dec num is 305
```

получаю:

```
hex num is 3101
dec num is 12545
```

Почему fread() инвертирует байты и как этого избежать?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: `fread()` тут ни при чем, все из-за того, что x86 это *little-endian* архитектура, т.е. младшие разряды числа располагаются в байтах с меньшими адресами. А мы привыкли записывать числа в *big-endian* (младшие разряды справа). Вот у Вас и получился файл в формате big-endian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, вы здесь выделяете памяти 2 байта, а читаете sizeof(int) байт, а это обычно 4, но может быть и другим числом -- размер int в языке не фиксирован. Т.е. вы читаете за выделенной памятью, это ошибка.

Во-вторых, почитайте про Little Endian (LE) и Big Endian (BE) -- два разных способа представления чисел в памяти. На x86 архитектуре это всегда LE, поэтому сначала идёт более младший байт. Это объясняет почему байты у вас "перевернулись" при выводе на экран (хотя в памяти они в том же порядке).

["Порядок байтов" в Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

По поводу "как этого избежать" -- зависит от того что вы хотите получить. Если цель показать то что есть в файле -- читайте в массив байт и выводите на экран байт за байтом.

Comment: Моя цель - получить десятичное число, закодированное в первых двух байтах: 0131h = 305. Я понял, что считанное мной число разместилось в памяти как 31 01. Логично предположить, что когда я буду записывать его в другую переменную(int x = *num), это как то учтется, и в итоге x у меня будет равен 305 (или 0x131). Но в итоге, условия x == 305 и x == 0x131 ложны, а x == 12545 и x == 0x3101 истинны. Получается что число из файла я считал, но юзать его в истинном значении не могу. Так как же получить переменную, содержащую нужное десятичное число.

Comment: @Ruslan, в файле у вас в первых байтах лежит число 0x3101 -- поскольку у нас LE. Точно так же как в файле, оно будет лежать и в памяти -- как байты 01 31. Можно считать из файла в байтовый массив barr и получить его как BE: `int num = (barr[0] << 8) | barr[1];`

Comment: большое спасибо, это сработало.